# How can I create a group footer in a WPF ListView ( GridView )

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5, styles

I have a ListView that displays sales orders, and groups them by status. In WinForms I had a footer at the bottom of each group that displayed the Total sale price for each group, and I would like to do the same in WPF.

I have figured out how to group the orders, but I can't figure out how to create a footer.

This is my current group style:

```
<ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="True">
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!--CollectionViewGroup.Name will be assigned the value of Status for that group.-->
                        <!--http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639809/how-do-i-group-items-in-a-wpf-listview-->
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Bold"  Foreground="Black"/>
                            <Line Grid.Column="1" Stroke="Black" X2="500" Fill="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

If your looking for something like this:

[image: WPF Grouping with Total Sums]
<sub>(source: [bendewey.com](http://www.bendewey.com/code/GroupingSum.png))</sub>

Then you can use the Template property of the ContainerStyle for the GroupStyle.  In this example I use a DockPanel, with the Grid you supplied Docked on the bottom and an ItemsPresenter filling the remainder.  In addition in order to get the Items totaled you'd have to use a Converter, which is supplied at the bottom.

### Window.xaml

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window3"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="Window3"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Width="640" Height="480">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MyDataSource x:Key="MyData" />
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ViewSource" Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyData}, Path=Users}">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Country" />
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
      <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewSource}}">
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                      <DockPanel>
                                        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
                                            <Grid.Resources>
                                                <local:TotalSumConverter x:Key="sumConverter" />
                                            </Grid.Resources>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition />
                                                <RowDefinition />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Total: " FontWeight="Bold"/>
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                                            </StackPanel>
                                            <Line Grid.Column="1" Stroke="Black" X2="500" Fill="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Path=Items, Converter={StaticResource sumConverter}}" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                </DockPanel>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
        <ListView.View>
           <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Phone Number" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Phone}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Country" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Country}" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Total" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Total}" />
           </GridView>
          </ListView.View>
      </ListView>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### MyDataSource.cs

```
public class MyDataSource
{
    public ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; set; }

    public MyDataSource()
    {
        Users = new ObservableCollection<User>();
        LoadDummyData();
    }

    private void LoadDummyData()
    {
        Users.Add(new User()
        {
            Name = "Frank",
            Phone = "(122) 555-1234",
            Country = "USA",
            Total = 432
        });

        Users.Add(new User()
        {
            Name = "Bob",
            Phone = "(212) 555-1234",
            Country = "USA",
            Total = 456
        });

        Users.Add(new User()
        {
            Name = "Mark",
            Phone = "(301) 555-1234",
            Country = "USA",
            Total = 123
        });

        Users.Add(new User()
        {
            Name = "Pierre",
            Phone = "+33 (122) 555-1234",
            Country = "France",
            Total = 333
        });

        Users.Add(new User()
        {
            Name = "Jacques",
            Phone = "+33 (122) 555-1234",
            Country = "France",
            Total = 222
        });

        Users.Add(new User()
        {
            Name = "Olivier",
            Phone = "+33 (122) 555-1234",
            Country = "France",
            Total = 444
        });
    }
}
```

### User.cs

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public double Total { get; set; }
}
```

### TotalSumConverter.cs

```
public class TotalSumConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var users = value as IEnumerable<object>;
        if (users == null)
            return "$0.00";

        double sum = 0;

        foreach (var u in users)
        {
            sum += ((User)u).Total;
        }


        return sum.ToString("c");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for putting this much effort into your answer. It really helped.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. I learn some things myself writing it.

Comment: I used this ControlTemplate for the DataGrid, and it worked pretty well.

Comment: Great solution! Any ideas how to easily add a "totals of total" row, under all groups? (A row that displays the sum of the totals)

Comment: How do you update the binding on the Sum in the event that an item in the  ItemsSource collection changes?

Comment: For anyone wondering, yes this works in UWP but unfortunately at the expense of UI virtualization.