# C# wpf ListView seperate scrollbar for each columns in GridView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview

I want seperate ScrollBar for each columns

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding name}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Price"  
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding price}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

and i want to have 2 horizontal scrollbar for each column (Name and Price),
my destination is to set up column with picture, but i want to scroll that picture when its to big.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to add scrolls only in the bottom of a gridview based on this solution: [How can I create a group footer in a WPF ListView ( GridView )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678690/how-can-i-create-a-group-footer-in-a-wpf-listview-gridview). It looks kinda hacky but it seems there is no already made solution.
What I did in xaml is bind Group description to a fake property for show the footer only one time.

XAML:

```
  <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="fake" />
```

Then I modified a footer template to make it display a scrollbar:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                            <DockPanel>
                                                <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" >
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=first, Path=Width, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=second, Path=Width, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ScrollBar Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Scroll="ScrollBar1_Scroll"
                                                          Width="{Binding ElementName=first, Path=Width, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" >

                                                    </ScrollBar>
                                                    <ScrollBar Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Scroll="ScrollBar2_Scroll"
                                                               Width="{Binding ElementName=second, Path=Width, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                                </Grid>
                                                <ItemsPresenter />
                                            </DockPanel>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
```

There's a lot of bindings which are necessary for resizing scrollbars with columns. Another hack there: you have to initially set the `Width` for each `GridViewColumn` or scrollbars will appear only after you manually resize a column.
I move contents of cells changing `Margin` property of `StackPanel` in the `CellTemplate`.
Below is the whole code, it's not a full working solution, I think, but a good point to start.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ViewSource" Source="{Binding Path=Collection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
            AncestorType=Window} }">
                <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                    <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="fake" />
                </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            </CollectionViewSource>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <HeaderedItemsControl  Header="ListView">
            <StackPanel>
                <ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewSource}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="Lv" Margin="5,5,5,5">
                    <ListView.GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                                <DockPanel>
                                                    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" >
                                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=first, Path=Width, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=second, Path=Width, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ScrollBar Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Scroll="ScrollBar1_Scroll"
                                                              Width="{Binding ElementName=first, Path=Width, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" >

                                                        </ScrollBar>
                                                        <ScrollBar Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Scroll="ScrollBar2_Scroll"
                                                                   Width="{Binding ElementName=second, Path=Width, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                                </DockPanel>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        </GroupStyle>
                    </ListView.GroupStyle>
                    <ListView.View >
                <GridView >
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Name"  x:Name="first" Width="50">
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Margin="{Binding Path=Offset1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
            AncestorType=Window} }">
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="tb1"  Text="{Binding name}"></TextBlock>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Price" x:Name="second"  Width="50">
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Margin="{Binding Path=Offset2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
            AncestorType=Window} }" >
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding price}"></TextBlock>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                        </GridView>
            </ListView.View>           
        </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
        </HeaderedItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And code-behind

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private List<MyItem> _collection = new List<MyItem>();
        public List<MyItem> Collection 
        { 
            get { return _collection; }
            set { _collection = value; InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Collection")); }
        }

        private Thickness _offset1;
        public Thickness Offset1
        {
            get { return _offset1; }
            set { _offset1 = value; InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Offset1")); }
        }

        private Thickness _offset2;
        public Thickness Offset2
        {
            get { return _offset2; }
            set { _offset2 = value; InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Offset2")); }
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Collection.Add(new MyItem("item1", "10"));
            Collection.Add(new MyItem("item2", "200"));
            Collection.Add(new MyItem("item3", "600000"));
            Collection.Add(new MyItem("item4", "1"));
        }

        private void ScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            //imitate scrolling here
            double leftToRight = Offset1.Left;
            if (e.ScrollEventType == ScrollEventType.SmallIncrement)
                leftToRight += 5;
            if (e.ScrollEventType == ScrollEventType.SmallDecrement)
                leftToRight -= 5;
            Offset1 = new Thickness(leftToRight, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        private void ScrollBar2_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            //imitate scrolling here
            double leftToRight = Offset2.Left;
            if (e.ScrollEventType == ScrollEventType.SmallIncrement)
                leftToRight += 5;
            if (e.ScrollEventType == ScrollEventType.SmallDecrement)
                leftToRight -= 5;
            Offset2 = new Thickness(leftToRight, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void InvokePropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
        }

    }

    public class MyItem
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string price { get; set; }

        public MyItem(string  n, string p)
        {
            name = n;
            price = p;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but then i get scrollbar for every item in ItemsSource.
i want to single scrollbar in the bottom.
im sorry, i dont mension that before

Comment: i changed my answer, try new solution, hope it will help just a little