# How to group data of LIstview in WPF?

Tags: wpf, binding, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

How to group data of Listview when data are bind from SQL Database

I used Collection View Source for that but it 
is not working

My Code lines are mentioned below :

```
    CollectionViewSource viewSource = new CollectionViewSource { Source = ds };
    viewSource.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("RequestID"));
    ListView1.ItemsSource = viewSource.View;
```

but it not working properly , even data are not show in listview when Listview  Item Source is bind with  Collection View Source

Please help me out.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

you can try the following

```
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ds);
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("RequestID"));
listview1.ItemsSource = view;
```

dont forget to set a grouping template. btw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639809/how-do-i-group-items-in-a-wpf-listview) is a related question with an complete anwser.