# Individual items in a list, possibility for group them? Wpf

Tags: wpf, list, mvvm, grouping

I have a stupid problem. I implemented a drag and drop. So i drag items (" questions ") from a listview to another listview. These items are put in a list from an object (" examination "). But i also have to be able to make clusters. So the examination object contains a list of questionclusters. Normally,when  i drag and drop a question, this come in a questioncluster, and the questioncluster contains a list of questions. Default, this list contains only 1 question. But the user has to got also the possibility to add multiple questions to 1 cluster.My problem is that i don't really know how that i practically implement this in the gui. Do i have to create a button, for when they want to add multiple questions in the questioncluste, if on click, a pop up appears. but this looks a bit strange to me, then i have to implement the drag and drop again... with the 2 lists.. Does anyone have some ideas for implement this in a user-friendly way? Maybe working with multiple colours? when they belong to the same cluster?
I am implementing in wpf , C#.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I may not have correctly understood the problem, but shouldn't simply grouping the items in listview (group by cluster) help here?

Comment: Does this help? [ListView Grouping Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771309(VS.85).aspx) and [How do I group items in a WPF ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639809/how-do-i-group-items-in-a-wpf-listview)