# Group Items in a listbox alphabetically

Tags: wpf, sorting, listbox, grouping

I have a WPF ListBox which shows a list of employees names. I want to group and sort them alphabetically. Is this possible? if so, how? Also, i will be required to style the headers (like the attached image) Could some1 guide me as to how i can achieve this. Thanx!

[image: This is the kind of listbox style i would liek to achieve]

Comment: Is the sort order always the English one, or do you want to support the various national ways of sorting accented characters (like ážü) or for example the Czech way of treating Ch as its own letter sorted after H?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can group items by adding  `GroupDescription` to the `CollectionView`. See this related question:

[How do I group items in a WPF ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639809/how-do-i-group-items-in-a-wpf-listview)

Also, google `GroupDescription` for many more examples.

Comment: hey! thanx alot, the link guided me to get the screen as required...! thanx :)