# How to access listbox item's datacontext from GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate?

Tags: wpf, listbox, groupstyle

I have a `ListBox`...where the `ItemSource` is a `CollectionViewSource`

rest everything same as in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639809/how-do-i-group-items-in-a-wpf-listview).

What I need is to access one property from my ListBox item's (or GroupItem ?) DataContext.

How can I access it ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to bind some text, try the following:

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding DataContext.PropertyName, ElementName=YourListBoxName}" />
```