# List with categories and limited number of items

Tags: wpf, list, datatemplate, wp-list-categories

I'd like to have a list in WPF (listbox, listview, anything) that can display items grouped on categories, but also having a limited number of items per category (let's say 5). If there are more items in a category then only display the first (5) and have a button or link to expand to more (or display them in a new container or window). Is that possible in a fairly simple way, or does it require a custom control?

Comment: If you're using WPF in the data centric way that it was designed to be used, then yes that's easy... you just need to filter your collection by whatever means you prefer and then just add more items into the collection upon the `Button.Click`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639809/how-do-i-group-items-in-a-wpf-listview

Comment: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/

Comment: I know how to group. I'm asking how to display only 5 items of each group and if there are more have a link/button etc. to do something to see the others.